# Edição de Template Scaffold MVC. Como obter referência de projetos em Solution Folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, t4

Estou editando os templates T4 do Scaffold do ASP.NET MVC e estou precisando obter algumas informações extras das classes. A princípio, **por exemplo**, do atributo `DisplayName` da Classe.

Encontrei uns exemplos:

```cs
var env = (DTE)((IServiceProvider)this.Host).GetService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE));
var proj = env.Solution.Projects.OfType<Project>()
    .Where(p => p.Name == assemblyName)
    .FirstOrDefault();

var codeType = proj.CodeModel.CodeTypeFromFullName(classFullName);

var attr = codeType != null ? codeType.Attributes
    .OfType<EnvDTE.CodeAttribute>()
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "DisplayName") : null;

var modelName = attr != null ? 
    attr.Value.Replace("\"", "") : 
    ViewDataTypeShortName;
```

Até ai, tudo bem. Mas tenho em minha Solution dois projetos que são de outra Solution (e estão em diretórios de Solutions diferentes), mas que foram adicionados normalmente via <kbd>Add</kbd> / <kbd>Existing Project</kbd>.

Então, essas outras duas assemblies eu não consigo obter referência usando:

```cs
var proj = env.Solution.Projects.OfType<Project>()
    .Where(p => p.Name == assemblyName)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Inclusive, fiz uma reflection em `env.Solution.Projects.OfType<Project>()` para ver o que seria impresso:

```cs
<# foreach (var proj in env.Solution.Projects.OfType<Project>()) { #>
// <#= proj.Name #>
<# } #>
```

E obtive algo que não entendi. Entre os Projetos que realmente foram criados, como:

```cs
// Common
// Projeto.Domain
// Projeto.Service
// Projeto.WebMVC
```

Onde essa `Common` é uma **Solution Folder** criada para os projetos da outra Solution. Mas os projetos que estão dentro dela não.

Então, outra forma que encontrei de realizar uma reflection nos assemblies foi adicioná-los diretamente:

```cs
<#@ assembly name="C:\Projects\SolutionA\Projeto.Domain\bin\Debug\Projeto.Domain.dll" #>
<#@ include namespace="Projeto.Domain.Entities" #>
<#@ assembly name="C:\Projects\SolutionA\Projeto.Service\bin\Debug\Projeto.Service.dll" #>
<#@ include namespace="Projeto.Service.ViewModels" #>
```

Dessa forma a reflection já é feita da forma tradicional conhecida.

O problema desse tipo de adição é que os fontes não estarão nos mesmos diretórios, o que acarretará de os assemblies não estarem nos diretórios especificados.

Então tentei com, por exemplo `$(SolutionDir)`, mas parece que nos templates do Scaffold ele não funciona.

Minha dúvida é como adicionar as referências lógicamente ou como ler os outros assemblies via `env.Solution.Projects`.

Para quem já teve experiência, outra forma de resolver o problema também é bem vinda!

Comment: Acho que não foi uma boa ideia você separar em camadas seu projeto e tentar usar *Scaffolding* depois. Nos testes que faço aqui, a única separação que ficou razoável é a de separar *Models* numa Class Library e *Controllers* e *Views* continuam no projeto ASP.NET MVC. De qualquer forma, posso direcionar a resposta para o uso do `EnvDTE`, se quiser.

Comment: Minhas `Controllers` `Views` ficam no projeto ASP.NET MVC, somente a as `ViewModels` que vão para outra camada. Sim, gostaria que você desse um exemplo de solução se tiver. Grato!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faltou apenas continuar a ler os demais níveis para localizar as classes de usuário que deseja localizar. O seguinte código pode ser útil:

```
var proj = env.Solution.Projects.OfType<Project>()
    .Where(p => p.Name == assemblyName)
    .FirstOrDefault();

foreach (EnvDTE.CodeElement element in proj.CodeModel.CodeElements)
{
    if (element.Kind == EnvDTE.vsCMElement.vsCMElementClass)
    {
        var myClass = (EnvDTE.CodeClass)element;
        // MyClass será uma classe de usuário
    }
}
```

---

Para iterar as propriedades da classe, este código pode ser interessante:

```
public IEnumerable<CodeProperty> GetProperties(CodeClass @class)
{
    if (@class == null) 
        return new List<CodeProperty>();

    var baseProperties = GetProperties(@class.Bases.Cast<CodeClass>().FirstOrDefault());

    return baseProperties.Concat(@class
        .Members
        .Cast<CodeElement>()
        .Where(ce => ce.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementProperty)
        .Cast<CodeProperty>()
        .Where(p => p.Access == vsCMAccess.vsCMAccessPublic));
    }
}
```

[Tirei daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18698763/1314276).

Comment: Só não sei porque, não estou obtendo nada de `codeClass.Attributes` e nem mesmo com `codeClass.GetType().GetProperties()`. Já viu isso? Grato!

Comment: @JamesTK Coloquei mais um método. Veja se te ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Solução encontrada em: [EnvDTE : Getting all projects (the SolutionFolder PITA)](http://www.wwwlicious.com/2011/03/29/envdte-getting-all-projects-html/)

Bom, criei um arquivo adicional onde coloquei minhas funções, chamado **MoreFunctions.cs.include.t4** e adicionou nas pastas de template que quero usar, por exemplo em: **Projeto\CodeTemplates\MvcView**

No final dos arquivos de template eu adiciono a seguinte linha:

```cs
<#@ include file="MoreFunctions.cs.include.t4" #>
```

Conteúdo do arquivo, tudo testado no **Visual Studio 2015 Community**:

```cs
<#+
DTE2 GetServiceEnvironment() {      
    return (DTE2)((IServiceProvider)this.Host).GetService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE));
}

Solution GetSolution() {
    return GetServiceEnvironment().Solution;
}

List<Project> GetProjects() {
    Projects projects = GetSolution().Projects;
    var projectList = new List<Project>();
    foreach (Project project in projects) {
        if (project.Kind == ProjectKinds.vsProjectKindSolutionFolder)
            projectList.AddRange(GetProjectsInSolutionFolder(project));
        else
            projectList.Add(project);
    }  
    return projectList;
}

List<Project> GetProjectsInSolutionFolder(Project solutionFolder) {
    var projectList = new List<Project>();
    for (var i = 1; i <= solutionFolder.ProjectItems.Count; i++) {
        var subProject = solutionFolder.ProjectItems.Item(i).SubProject;
        if (subProject == null)
            continue;
        if (subProject.Kind == ProjectKinds.vsProjectKindSolutionFolder)
            projectList.AddRange(GetProjectsInSolutionFolder(subProject));
        else
            projectList.Add(subProject);
    }
    return projectList;
}

Project GetProject(string projectName) {
    return GetProjects().OfType<Project>().Where(p => p.Name == projectName).FirstOrDefault();
}

Project GetThisProject() {
    return GetSolution().FindProjectItem(this.Host.TemplateFile).ContainingProject as EnvDTE.Project;
}

CodeType GetCodeType(string classFullName) {
    var projects = GetProjects();
    foreach (var project in projects) {
        if (classFullName.StartsWith(project.Name)) {
            CodeType codeType = project.CodeModel.CodeTypeFromFullName(classFullName);
            return codeType;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

CodeClass GetCodeClass(CodeElements elements, string className) {
    if (elements == null)
        return null;
    foreach (EnvDTE.CodeElement element in elements) {
        if (element.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementClass) {
            var codeClass = (EnvDTE.CodeClass)element;
            if (codeClass != null && codeClass.FullName == className)
                return codeClass;
        }

        if (element.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementNamespace) {
            var result = GetCodeClass(((CodeNamespace)element).Members, className);
            if (result != null)
                return result;
        }

        if (element.IsCodeType) {
            var result = GetCodeClass(((CodeType)element).Members, className);
            if (result != null)
                return result;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
#>
```

Precisei adicionar as seguintes referências em **Imports.include.t4**:

```cs
<#@ assembly name="EnvDTE" #>
<#@ assembly name="EnvDTE80" #>
<#@ import namespace="EnvDTE" #>
<#@ import namespace="EnvDTE80" #>
```

Por fim, um exemplo de uso para obter o valor do atributo `DisplayName`:

```cs
var codeType = GetCodeType(ViewDataTypeName);

var attr = codeType != null ? 
    codeType.Attributes.OfType<EnvDTE.CodeAttribute>()
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "DisplayName") : null;

var modelDisplayName = attr != null ? 
    attr.Value.Replace("\"", "") : 
    ViewDataTypeShortName;
```

---

### TENTATIVA ANTERIOR - NÃO FUNCIONOU !!!

Implementei da seguinte forma:

```cs
CodeClass GetCodeClass(CodeElements elements, string className) {
    if (elements == null)
        return null;
    foreach (EnvDTE.CodeElement element in elements) {
        if (element.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementClass)
        {
            var codeClass = (EnvDTE.CodeClass)element;
            if (codeClass != null && codeClass.FullName == className)
                return codeClass;
        }

        if (element.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementNamespace)
        {
            var result = GetCodeClass(((CodeNamespace)element).Members, className);
            if (result != null)
                return result;
        }

        if (element.IsCodeType)
        {
            var result = GetCodeClass(((CodeType)element).Members, className);
            if (result != null)
                return result;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Que usei para:

```cs
var project = GetProject();
var codeType = GetCodeClass(project.CodeModel.CodeElements, ViewDataTypeName);

var attr = codeType != null ?    
    codeType.Attributes.OfType<EnvDTE.CodeAttribute>()
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "DisplayNameAttribute") : null;
modelName = attr != null ? 
    attr.Value.Replace("\"", "") : 
    ViewDataTypeShortName;
```

Mas infelizmente não retorna meus atributos.

Fiz ate uma "reflection", mas não imprimiu nada.

```cs
<#
    foreach (var prop in codeType.GetType().GetProperties()) {
#>
//      <#= prop.Name #>
<#
    }
#>
```

Nada, e nada também:

```cs
foreach (CodeAttribute attribute in codeType.Attributes) {
    #>
//  <#= attribute.Name #>
    <#
}
```

Mas o nome da classe imprimiu...

```cs
#>
// <#= codeType.Name #>

<#
```

¬¬
Vai entender..

Bora pra próxima jornada!!

Comment: O que devolveu aqui? `foreach (CodeAttribute attribute in codeType.Attributes) {`? Enumerador vazio?

Comment: Não imprimiu nada, nem verifiquei se era `null`... vou ver agora!

Comment: Não nulo, logo..enumerador vazio!!